# i can't solve this error this.props.getAllProducts is not a function TypeError: this.props.getAllProducts is not a function at componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

i think the problem is here

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      modalShow: false,
      login: true
    };
    this.addToBag = this.addToBag.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.products) {
      this.props.getAllProducts();
    }
  }

  showHideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalShow: false });
  };

  loginClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ modalShow: true, login: true });
  };
  registerClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ modalShow: true, login: false });
  };

  addToBag = params => {
    if (
      Auth.getUserDetails() !== undefined &&
      Auth.getUserDetails() !== null &&
      Auth.getToken() !== undefined
    ) {
      let cart = this.props.postCart(params);
      cart.then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ modalShow: true });
    }
  };
```

can anyone help me out i tryed every thing for hours and i need details because i'm new to programming and evrything is difficult now

i try to delete the .props and it didn't work also and it gave me a new error

and here I call it

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
getAllProducts: () => dispatch(getAllProducts()),
applyFilters: filter_string => dispatch(applyFilters(filter_string)),
postCart: productId => dispatch(postCart(productId))
});

export default connect(mapStoreToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

here where I declear it

```
export const getAllProducts = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_BEGIN
  });
  return API({
    method: "GET",
    url: `/products`
  })
```

Comment: Where is the code when you declare `getAllProducts()`?

Comment: i put it up there

Comment: sorry now i add where i declare it

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with returning a promise from the action creator. Could you please try updating the action creator as below:

```
export const getAllProducts = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_BEGIN
  });
  return await API({
    method: "GET",
    url: `/products`
  })
```

Not sure what `API({object})` call does. Assuming that it's a placeholder.

If it is not a placeholder, I think you should consider dispatching the action `GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS` instead of the return call there. In essence, it should trigger the action to update the state with the products when you have a response from backend.

Something like this

```
const response = await API({
      method: "GET",
      url: `/products`
    });

    dispatch({
      type: GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: response.data // Assuming the response data contains the products
    });
```

In short, the action creators are meant to trigger the actions which in turn result in invoking the reducer functions to update the state.

Hope this helps.